# Obj-C function translation to Swift 2 function

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift2

I've done my best to transalte this code but something is still wrong. Can some please help and also explain which Obj-C code correlates to the Swift code?  Thanks.

**Obj-C**

```
//NTRMainViewConroller.m
- (IBAction)unwindFromModalViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    if ([segue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[NTRColorsTableViewController class]]) {
        NTRColorsTableViewController *colorsViewConroller = segue.sourceViewController;
        // if the user clicked Cancel, we don't want to change the color
        if (colorsViewConroller.selectedColor) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = colorsViewConroller.selectedColor;
        }
    }
}
```

**my attempt to translateSwift**

```
var colorsViewController: ColorsTableViewController
    @IBAction func unwindFromModalViewController(segue:  UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if segue.sourceViewController.isKindOfClass(ColorsTableViewController class)  {
            colorsViewController = segue.sourceViewController
            if(colorsViewController.selected)
        }

    }
```

Comment: can I assume `var colorsViewController: ColorsTableViewController` doesn't belong in the sample?

Comment: `if(colorsViewController.selected)` then... what? :)

Comment: What is the compiler error?

Comment: One thing is that `ColorsTableViewController class` needs to be `ColorsTableViewController.self`

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromModalViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
     guard let colorsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? ColorsTableViewController else { return }
     if colorsViewController.selected ...
}
```

Now, if you have more conditions after that, I'd recommend going with:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromModalViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let viewController = segue.sourceViewController as? ColorsTableViewController else {
        if viewController.selected ...
    } else ...
}
```